# SQLAlchemy fetch parent with children and children's related columns in another table

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have the following 3 tables:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_name = Column(String(50))
    children = relationship("Child", backref='parent')

@dataclass
class Child(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_name = Column(String(50))
    parent_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('parent.id'),nullable=False)
    school_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('school.id'),nullable=False)

@dataclass
class School(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'school'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    school_name = Column(String(50))
    school_address = Column(String(50))
    school_ranking = Column(String(50))
```

Is there any way I can get this result using sqlalchemy?

```
[
  Parent {
    id: ...
    parent_name: ...
    children: [
        {
            id: ...,
            child_name: ...,
            school_name: ...,
            school_address: ...,
            parent_id: ...,
            school_id: ...
        },
        {
            id: ...,
            child_name: ...,
            school_name: ...,
            school_address: ...,
            parent_id: ...,
            school_id: ...
        },
    ]
  },
  Parent {
    id: ...
    parent_name: ...
    children: [
        {
            id: ...,
            child_name: ...,
            school_name: ...,
            school_address: ...,
            parent_id: ...,
            school_id: ...
        },
        {
            id: ...,
            child_name: ...,
            school_name: ...,
            school_address: ...,
            parent_id: ...,
            school_id: ...
        },
    ]
  },
]
```

Each child has a school name and school address info stored in the School table. I want to query Parent and its children so that each child object has the school name and school address in addition to the child's columns.

I tried the following query:

```
session.query(Parent).options(joinedload(Parent.children)).all()
```

which gives the hierarchy that I want, but I don't know how to integrate the child's school info into each resulted child object.

Thank you.